# text are drawn out of view in canvas.drawetext

Tags: android, eclipse, canvas

I used canvas to draw a text:

```
canvas.drawText(text);
```

but some times size of lines are larger than windows and line cant be shown completely. on I use this code to calculate width of linear layout that this text is set to it. the width of this layout is calculated by this code:

```
        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

   int windows_width;
    layout.post(new Runnable() 
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.i("TEST", "Layout width : "+ layout.getWidth());
             windows_width=layout.getWidth();

        }
    });
```

and now I want use this size and if it was smaller than text size:
        float size=mPaint.measureText(text);

I break text into two or more than one line that fit the screen:
so I should write:

```
        float size=mPaint.measureText(text);
    int count=0;
    if (size>windows_width){
    count=(int) (size/width);

    for (int i=0 ;i< count; i++){
        int textsize=text.length();
        String line=text.substring(i, ((int) (textsize/count))*(i+1)-1);


    mPaint.setSubpixelText(true);

    canvas.drawText(line, rowX, 100*(i+1), mPaint);

    }

    }

    else {
        mPaint.setSubpixelText(true);

        canvas.drawText(text, rowX, 100, mPaint);
    }
```

but the letter that are located near the bound are not shown. why?

how should i set  x and y? are they distance from windows or layout?

Comment: why dont you use `android.text.Layout#draw(Canvas)` ?

Comment: where should I use it?

Comment: where you want to draw your text

Comment: why should I use it?

Comment: why? to make your life easier

Comment: :) OK. I mean that how and where and why? can you explain more?

Comment: just call `layout.draw(canvas)` when you want to draw your text (most likely `onDraw` method)

Comment: this class that uses drawtext is not an activity class. it is  a class that extends view. I used this view in activity class.

Comment: i dont know what you mean, use it where you have a `Canvas` thats all

Comment: can it solve my problem?

Comment: can you tell me how can it solve the problem and explain more?

Comment: did you call `layout.draw` ?

Comment: no.......................

Comment: ok, good luck with `canvas.drawText` then

Comment: OK. thanks for your helpful advice!!!

Comment: I should say that it is in "public class abc extends View". so I don't have layout in this class. this class used as view for other class.

Comment: i know, that's why i said to call `layout.draw` inside `onDraw` method, but it seems that you dont want to do that, `"so I don't have layout in this class"` so make a field of type `android.text.Layout` in your custom view

Comment: you mean that I use this?

Comment: LinearLayout layout ; 
  layout.draw(canvas);

Comment: but I dont have xml file in this class how can i call findviewbyid?

Comment: what LinearLayout? `android.text.Layout layout;`

Comment: but I should initialize it.  how? with null?

Comment: read `android.text.Layout` documentation on how to create an object of this type

Comment: OK. I will read it. I hope it can help.

Comment: I found http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html but i cant understand it

Comment: what cant you understand in it?

Comment: this: android.text.Layout

Comment: what exactly cant you understand in it?

Comment: I use this codes :   "android.text.Layout layout = null ;
  layout.draw(canvas); "  in  "protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {" but it shouldn't be null.

Comment: do you know how to create new class objects in java?

Comment: no, I don't understand what do you mean :(

Comment: if you have a class `MyClass`, how do you create an object of this class? `MyClass object = ...` do you know how to initialize it?

Comment: new MyClass(arg0); is is true?

Comment: MyClass object =new MyClass(arg0);

Comment: so do that with `android.text.Layout` class, see its documentation again on how to do that

Comment: you mean this?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html

Comment: yes, i mean `android.text.Layout`

Comment: I found this   android.text.Layout layout = new Layout(line, null, textsize, null, size, size) {

Comment: from the link you posted: "Class Overview
A base class that manages text layout in visual elements on the screen.

For text that will be edited, use a **DynamicLayout**, which will be updated as the text changes. For text that will not change, use a **StaticLayout**.", did you actually read it?

Comment: yes I read it but my problem was something else.

Comment: but you don't tell me what is difference between them? using draw(convas) or canvas.drawText(text);

Comment: `draw(convas)` draws one or more lines of `Spanned` text

Comment: OK. some thing like this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341266/how-to-draw-a-text-inside-a-box-on-canvas-with-dynamiclayout-and-ellipsize

Comment: but I have problem in setting width parameter. the text are not shown completely.

Comment: @pskink thanks for your help. I finally use your advice without any problem.